# Mac OSX Rails Can not run Rake Command

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I am trying to run rake command to build the db for my project. but i am encoutering the following error.

```
Harshas-MacBook-Pro:noise harshamv$ rake db:create
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "database"=>"noise_development", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"hmv", "password"=>2206, "socket"=>"/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"}, {:charset=>"utf8", :collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}
(If you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "database"=>"noise_test", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>"root", "socket"=>"/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"}, {:charset=>"utf8", :collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}
(If you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
```

Rake db:migrate

```
Harshas-MacBook-Pro:noise harshamv$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/mysql2-0.3.15/lib/mysql2/client.rb:67:in `connect'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/mysql2-0.3.15/lib/mysql2/client.rb:67:in `initialize'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `new'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `mysql2_connection'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:863:in `initialize'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `new'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `up'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

But i am able to get connected into mysql from the CLI.

This is my Rails Configuration File

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: noise_development
  pool: 5
  username: hmv
  password: *******
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: So your connection info in your database.yml is wrong, it says mysql can be found at a socket file at /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock, but it can't be. What the right info is depends on how your machine is set up. If you can connect from the mysql CLI, what connection arguments do you use to start the `mysql` command that works? This will show you what to put in the databases.yml to connect in the same way that's working with the mysql cli.

Comment: by commenting out the Socket it worked by taking the defaults.